# My Friend in Kanto

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

I have a friend in Kanto. He sent me a message and told me that he's looking for all sorts of creatures. Included was the following list of descriptions. I know there's a message hidden in there somewhere, but I'm not sure how to find it. He also attached a couple of clues, too, but again, I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the list:

> - Rock that rolls everywhere, first evolution
> - Obscured by many vines
> - Little green worm
> - Not even and definitely poisonous
> - A bit of wordplay: breakfast killer
> - Evolved pink blob
> - Fighter made of muscle, not evolved
> - Little rat that loves to bite
> - Turtle that foams at the mouth
> - Ringing plant, not evolved
> - Male monarch
> - More or less a rhinoceros
> - Silently creates invisible walls
> - Smallest fiery lizard
> - Black pearl in a grey shell - evolved
> - Part insect and part power tool
> - Precious metal fish
> - Large, compound eyes and purple fur
> - Female monarch

Here are the only clues I could get out of him:

> 1. There's quite a walk ahead of you, so you'll need to take a number of steps.
> 2. When you're almost there, just let them be the key to unlock the door.

I guess I should add that I don't plan on going to Kanto at all, and I won't actually be walking anywhere. I wonder what else "number of steps" could mean ...

Can you find the hidden message?

Hint (previously included in tags):

> Pokemon.

Comment: I enjoyed working on this question, but I don't understand how your clues relate to the answer.

Comment: You can find the relation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuYeHPFR3f0

Comment: Are those lyrics from the song? I get that the answer is I meant your clues 1. and 2.

Comment: I'll ask Khale_Kitha to add them to the answer, so they can go in the spoiler tags.

Comment: Either way, I was just wondering

Comment: I see it's added now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is:

> I Wanna be the very best

Reasons:

```
There's quite a walk ahead of you, so you'll need to take a number of steps.
```

> The puzzle requires a sequence of steps to solve it.
>  1. Find the Pokémon from the clues
>  2. Get the Pokédex numbers
>  3. Mod26 the pokedex numbers
>  4. Convert them to letters
>  5. Then, use vigenere to find the phrase.

```
When you're almost there, just let them be the key to unlock the door.
```

> "Let them be the key" means that they (POKEMON) are the vigenere key used to solve the puzzle.

Process:

> The pokemon index numbers can be found in [Caelan's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31523/19944) answer, provided by several people.
>  75, 114, 10, 43, 103, 40, 66, 19, 7, 69, 34, 111, 122, 4, 91, 15, 118, 48, 31

If you take the numbers and:

> Mod26 them (+1 because it's 1-26 indexed), then convert 1-A through 26-Z, you get:
>  XKKRZOOTHRIHSENPOWF

Then if you use:

> POKEMON as a vigenere key

You receive the answer mentioned, above.

Answer (score 7):

The Pokémon that the clues can be referring to are:

> Graveler - #075
> Tangela - #114
> Caterpie - #010
> Oddish - #043 (LogicianWithAHat)
> Exeguttor - #103
> Wigglytuff - #040 (Wesley Situ)
> Machop - #066
> Rattata - #019
> Squirtle - #007 (Squirtle is secretly James Bond)
> Bellsprout - #069
> Nidoking - #034
> Rhyhorn - #111
> Mr. Mime - #122
> Charmander - #004
> Cloyster - #091
> Beedrill - #015
> Goldeen - #118
> Venonat - #048
> Nidoqueen - #031

Part 2:
Steps could refer to egg cycles. Pokedex numbers add up to 1120. Egg cycles last 255 steps, but I can't find any more correlation. Dead end as of now.

Comment: I don't think beautifly or dustox are found in kanto

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that.

Comment: Could the steps be the 8 badges you have to get along the way?

Comment: Why Wigglytuff and not Clefable?

Comment: @DavidStarkey Wigglytuff is more of a blob. The actual pokemon in question have already been confirmed correct in discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38974/discussion-on-answer-by-gannolloy-my-friend-in-kanto

Comment: @DavidStarkey I think a `pink blob` wold refer more to a Jigglypuff than a Clefairy.

Comment: Steps -- isn't your time in the Safari Zone limited to a certain number of steps?

Comment: @feelinferrety 500 in gen1 and 600 in gen 3

Answer (score 6):

First part complete.

1 - 075

> Graveler

2 - 114

> Tangela

3 - 010

> Caterpie

4 - 043

> Oddish (LogicianWithAHat)

5 - 103

> Exeggutor

6 - 040

> Wigglytuff (Wesley Situ)

7 - 066

> Machop

8 - 019

> Rattata

9 - 007

> Squirtle (Wesley Situ)

10 - 069

> Bellsprout

11 - 034

> Nidoking

12 - 111

> Rhyhorn

13 - 122

> Mr. Mime

14 - 004

> Charmander

15 - 091

> Cloyster

16 - 015

> beedrill

17 - 118

> Goldeen

18 - 048

> Venonat

19 - 031

> Nidoqueen

Pokedex numbers add up to 1120. Not sure if relevant

Working on the clues now. Added Pokedex numbers

> I think the clues have to do with Victory Road. It's a long walk through the Pokemon filled road, and you have to show your badges in the Pokémon League Building just before to get through the doors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38974/discussion-on-answer-by-gannolloy-my-friend-in-kanto).